# using while loop with async function and setTimeout. Nodejs

Tags: node.js, async-await

I'm trying to create a test, to verify that I've `put` an item in a dynamoDB table. In order to do so, right after I make a call that should `put` an Item (vehicle) in the database, I am trying to `get` the vehicle from the DB.

In my test I want to have a maximum number of retries (5). I want this while loop to be block the thread until my query has resolved to give a vehicle, or tried 5 times. Inside my test I have:

```
    let count = 0
    let car
    while (!car || count < 5) {
        setTimeout(async () => {
            car = await findVehicle(greenCar.vehicleInfo)
        }, 3000)
        count++
    }
```

And `findVehicle` is an asynchronous function that does a `get` from the dynamoDB table

Comment: `setTimeout` does not return a `Promise`, `await setTimeout` does not make sense

Comment: that was a typo

Comment: What is going wrong with what you have now?

Comment: @AlexG it's an infinite loop

Comment: Well, you are incrementing count in setTimeout.. You should increment it below it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm relatively new to node. I think the problem lies in that I don't have a full understanding of the event loop.. This code is in my first `mocha` test, and I don't get the `console.log` of the queries until after all of the tests have run..

I expected the increment in the setTimeout to be executed as setTimeout was called and I expected setTimeout to be blocking the thread

Comment: setTimeout starts a timer and after that timer has expired, the callback gets put in the event loop. Main execution continues normally. Update your answer with what you want to happen in more detail and check this out for more: https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/what-you-should-know-to-really-understand-the-node-js-event-loop-and-its-metrics-c4907b19da4c

Comment: Thanks @AlexG, I've edited my question, I think it's a little more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wait on each iteration you can do this:

```
let count = 0;
let car;

while (!car || count < 5) {

    await new Promise((resolve) =>
        setTimeout(async () => {
            car = await findVehicle(greenCar.vehicleInfo);
            resolve();
        }, 3000));

    count++
}
```

So you are resolving the promise you are awaiting after you get your data. Also your function must be async in order to use await. Hope this helps.